# Вывод строки под номером N Из файла

Tags: c++, c

Нужно чтобы выводилась строка под номером N, который генерируется рандомно.
Какую функцию нужно использовать для этого? Желательно сишные функции (cstdio)

Answer (score 5):

Вам нужны функции открытия файла, чтения и закрытия. Открываете файл, читаете построчно и увеличивайте счетчик. Когда счетчик достиг нужной, выводим строку.
схематический код:

```
char * getLine(char* filename, int nedded) {
  char line[250];
  FILE * f = open(filename, "r");
  int c = 0;
  while (c < needed && not eof(f)) {
     fscanf(f, "%s", line);
     c++;
  }
  close(f);
  if (c!= nedded) {
    return NULL;
  }
  return strdup(line); // не забыть потом освободить буфер
}

char * line = getLine("input.txt", N);
if (line) {
  printf("%s\n", line);
  free(line);
}
```

Comment: Добавлю еще сюда bash однострочник: `sed 'LINE_NUMBERq;d' FILE_NAME` который делает тоже самое

Answer (score 1):

```
 //индексация строк с нуля
int n_readline(const char* fname, int n, char* buf, int len){
    char  c;
    FILE* fp = fopen(fname, "rt");
    if(fp == NULL)
        return 0;

    while(! feof(fp) && (n > 0)){
       fscanf(fp, "%*[^\n\r]%c", &c);
       --n;
    }

    if(! feof(fp))
        fgets(buf, len-1, fp);
    else
       *buf = '\0';

    fclose(fp);
    return (int)(*buf != '\0');
  }



 int main(void){
   char buf[255];

   //считать 2-строку
   if(n_readline("levels.txt", 1, buf, sizeof(buf)))
         puts(buf);

   //считать 3-строку
   if(n_readline("levels.txt", 2, buf, sizeof(buf)))
         puts(buf);
   return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

В других ответах варианты на чистом C, а вот вам на C++:

```
#include <fstream>

std::string get_line_n(const std::string& filename, size_t n)
{
    std::ifstream f(filename);
    // тут бы не помешала проверка на то, что с файлом всё в порядке
    std::string line;
    bool notreached = true;
    while (std::getline(f, line) && notreached = (n-- > 0))
        ;
    if (!notreached)
        return line;
    else
        // такой строки нет, сообщайте об ошибке
        // например, бросьте подходящее исключение
        throw std::range_error();
}
```

Для сравнения, вот на C#:

```
string getLineByNumber(string filename, int n)
{
    var line = File.ReadLines(filename).Skip(n).FirstOrDefault();
    if (line != null)
        return line;
    else
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
}
```

---

Упражнение: зачем нужна переменная `notreached`? Почему просто не проверить значение `n`?

Comment: @Abyx: Строки нумеруются с нуля, разумеется.

Comment: @Abyx: Нет, но программисты привыкли, знаете ли, с нуля. Почему код не компилируется, не имею ни малейшего представления. Наверняка тривиальная опечатка или забытый `#include`. Приятного вечера!